# Generate a file that only contains the structural parts (i.e. brackets) of a json file without other contents

Tags: python, json, structure

Is there a way to extract the structural details of a json file using Python?

I have a file that looks something like this:

```
{
"help": "https://?name=package_search", 
"success": true,
"result": {
      "count": 47, 
      "facets": {}, 
      "results": [
         {
           "author": "ggm",
           "author_email": "ggm@____.nl",
           "creator_user_id": "x_x_x_x" }]}}
```

Whereas I only want to see a structure that would be something like this:

```
{
   {
      [
       {
        }
       {
        }
         ]
              }
                   }
```

Is this possible to achieve with Python?

Comment: Where is the JSON coming from? Are you trying to convert one to the other? Those two examples don't line up, the first opens with `{{{}` and the second with `{{[{`.

Comment: This definitely feels like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627). What are you actually trying to achieve, here?

Comment: Note that the response you ask for is not valid JSON (or Python). JSON objects (and Python dicts) contain key-value pairs. While `{}` is valid, you can't have something like `{[]}`. Is the `[]` supposed to be a key? A value? Well, objects (and dicts) need both.

Comment: Also, valid JSON would still require commas.

Comment: Yeah, it's data taken from an online source via an API... So it's all a bit weird. But I used the requests package to get it, and then 'unpacked' the request with a .json() function, which gives me a structure that looks like json.

Comment: I also just used this as an example -- the full file is 100 pages long, which I didn't want to replicate here haha

Comment: What are you going to do with the stripped content? As I said, it's not valid so you won't be able to ingest it as JSON so it seems kind of useless. Please see the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627) link I provided earlier.

Comment: I mean... you do you. But don't you think "the author of the first result in the results list in the result object" is clearer than "open curly, open curly, skip the curlies, open bracket, open curly"? And there are lots of tools out there that understand JSON, let you fold it, possibly generate a navigational tree...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex (assuming the data is still in string form and not yet parsed to a dict):

```py
import re

s = """{
"help": "https://?name=package_search", 
"success": true,
"result": {
      "count": 47, 
      "facets": {}, 
      "results": [
         {
           "author": "ggm",
           "author_email": "ggm@____.nl",
           "creator_user_id": "x_x_x_x" }]}}"""

print(re.sub(r"[^{}[\]\n]", ' ', s))
```

Will give:

```
{
                                        
                
          {
                   
                {}  
                 [
         {
                           
                                         
                                        }]}}
```

This uses [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) which is the regex version of `replace` and basically says: *"Replace everything **except** brackets and new line with a space"* (see [the demo](https://regex101.com/r/KKos6m/1)).